# Prolog: how to write (and use) a function that lists all list permutations?

Tags: prolog

I've found such an example of naive sort written in prolog and I am trying to understand it:

```
naive_sort(List,Sorted):-perm(List,Sorted),is_sorted(Sorted).

is_sorted([]).
is_sorted([_]).
is_sorted([X,Y|T]):-X=<Y,is_sorted([Y|T]).


perm(List,[H|Perm]):-delete(H,List,Rest),perm(Rest,Perm).
perm([],[]).

delete(X,[X|T],T).
delete(X,[H|T],[H|NT]):-delete(X,T,NT).
```

Naive_sort call works correctly but I just can't figure out why. The main problem is the permutation. When it is called implicitly it always returns only one value. How is it then possible that in naive_sort function call all permutations are checked? Also how could I modify perm function to write all permutations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **truly** a naive sort -- it traverses the tree of all possible permutations until it luckily finds a sorted one. That's have a complexity of O(n!) i presume :>

About the permutation function -- it works "backwards" -- note that the definition takes the head out of the **result**. If you turn around your point of view, you'll notice that instead of deleting it actually inserts values by working backwards. As the algorithm is working backwards, hence the `H`ead chosen may be anything that will allow a result to be created, hence any unused value from List.

Basically the permutation algorithm translates to the following procedural implementation:

1. pick an item from List
2. put it into front of Sorted

This way you generate permutations. All of them.

In short - perm generates the whole space of possible solutions by starting out of an empty solution and checking how the given solution is possible from a valid delete.

```
?-  perm( [ 1, 2, 3 ] , P ) 
P = [1, 2, 3]; 
P = [1, 3, 2]; 
P = [2, 1, 3]; 
P = [2, 3, 1]; 
P = [3, 1, 2]; 
P = [3, 2, 1]; 
no
```

Comment: so why whe calling this function it does display only ONE result, not all of them?

Comment: @agnieszka - it's not a function! It's a **predicate** that is true ONLY if the first argument is a permutation of the second.

Comment: @agnieszka - using GNU Prolog or SWI?

Comment: YESSS I know that, still you've written "it generates permutations. all of them." - it does not. it finds first combination of the unknown arguments that satisfies the predicate - so only ONE permutation. so how, how is it possible that it works when calling naive_sort?

Comment: @agnieszka -- because it keeps "calling" perm, until either is_sorted is true or it fails.

Comment: 1. but when i call perm many times i always get the same result. 2. according to your edit: my result is different after that call - it displays only one result and i don't know how to modify it to display them all

Comment: tylko ze wielokrotne wywolywanie perm zawsze daje te same wyniki

Comment: @agnieszka - bo wielokrotnie wywołujesz, a nie ściągasz kolejne wyniki :). Wpisz średnik i enter po pierwszym wyniku -- będziesz miała szukanie dalszych rozwiązań -- http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/1.html

Comment: z nieba mi spadles dzien przed egzaminem... :D czyli po prostu prolog wie ze rozwiazan perm-a  wyolaniu naive_sort jest wiele i skoro jedno nie dziala to probuje drugie. 2 dni na nauczenie prologa to jednak troche za malo - wielkie dzieki! ;)

Comment: Prolog wie, że póki perm mu nie powie "No", to może próbować czerpać z niego rozwiązania. 2 dni to zdecydowanie za mało, bo prolog to inny paradygmat programowania (programowanie logiczne) który znacząco różni się od szeroko znanych... powowdzenia!

Comment: :D Łojczysty język na stacku. no patrzcie... :D

Comment: @naugtur, zbliżający się egzamin zmusza do radykalnych rozwiązań ;>

Answer (score 10):

> The main problem is the permutation
>   function. When it is called implicitly
>   it always retrns only one value.

Prolog is a language that always attempts on proving the truth of a statement, by deriving it using the axioms (facts or rules) given.

`perm` is not a function in the sense of procedural programming. `perm` is a predicate, about which we tell prolog two things:

1. The empty list is a permutation of itself.
2. `List` is a permutation of `[H|Perm]` if there is a list `Rest` such that `Rest` is obtained by deleting `H` from `List`, and `Rest` is a permutation of `Perm`.

When asked whether some list is a permutation of another, prolog will attempt to apply these derivation steps (recursively) to prove it. If this recursion reaches a dead end, i.e. a statement which can not be proven as no rules can be applied to it, it backtracks.

Comment: i knew all that except of the backtracking if anything fails - this explains a lot

Comment: Describing it is so much easier if english is one's native language -_-

Comment: I take that as a compliment, because it is not my native language either :-)

Answer (score 1):

use a semicolon (;) at the end of each permutation prolog would give you until there is no other permutation, prolog should say No

Comment: Yes, The reason why OP is seeing only one solution when called is probably because they aren't typing a ; to the ? prompt to see the others (forces it to fail and backtrack to find another solution).