# Ordering lists with constraint logic programming

Tags: list, prolog, constraint-programming

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem: I have to order a list using Prolog with Constraing Logic Programming and I must do it with the more efficient way I can.

So the main predicate I have defined is the next one:

```
order(Xs,Ys) :-
    same_length(Xs,Ys),      /* To determine the list Ys with the Xs' length */
    perm(Xs,Ys),             /* Permutation */
    ordered(Ys),             /* Is Ys ordered? */
    ! .
```

The implementation of each of the previous auxiliary predicates is as follows:

```
same_length(Xs,Ys) :-
    length(Xs,L),
    length(Ys,L).

perm([],[]).
perm([X|Xs],Ys) :- elem(X,Ys,Ws), perm(Xs,Ws).

ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X,Y|Xs]) :- X =< Y, ordered([Y|Xs]).

elem(X,[X|Ys],Ys).
elem(X,[Y|Ws],[Y|Zs]) :- elem(X,Ws,Zs).
```

I have proved the program I made and it works! But I don't know if it is possible to improve the efficiency, and if it is, how can I do it (I was reading [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196570/prolog-how-to-write-and-use-a-function-that-lists-all-list-permutations) here). Should I add or modify any of the constraints?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is to try all the permutations of a list until you find one that is sorted in ascending order.  We can do something more efficient!  However the bit about Constraint Logic Programming seems to be irrelevant.  Although this is "logic programming", no use is made (or needs to be made) of constraints as [CLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming) ordinarily means them.  Are you required to bring constraints into the picture somehow?

Comment: Yes. Indeed I must try to constraint and then test the solution,  not just generate every possible option and verify. For that reason I did the emphasis on CLP and not just simple Prolog

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your definition of `same_length/2` will not terminate very often. Instead, consider

```
same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
   same_length(Xs, Ys).
```

equally, using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) use

```
... maplist(\_^_^true,Xs, Ys), ...
```

in place of

```
... same_length(Xs, Ys), ...
```

It seems you want to reformulate sorting by stating first, that the list is ordered, and only then searching for a permutation. Below works in SICStus, SWI, YAP.

```
ordered2([]).
ordered2([_]).
ordered2([X,Y|Xs]) :-
   when((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y)),
        ( X =< Y, ordered2([Y|Xs]) )).

list_sorted2(Xs,Ys) :-
    maplist(\_^_^true,Xs,Ys),
    ordered2(Ys),
    perm(Ys,Xs).
```

Please note that the arguments in perm/2 are now exchanged!  Using SWI:

```
?- time(order([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],Xs)).
% 38,434,099 inferences, 10.655 CPU in 11.474 seconds (93% CPU, 3607101 Lips)

?- time(list_sorted2([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],Xs)).
% 50,139 inferences, 0.023 CPU in 0.032 seconds (72% CPU, 2205620 Lips)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tested it and it works perfectly. The only thing I didn't understand is why you told me I should use the lambda library. Why this is better than 'same_length' predicate?

Comment: It is better, because it is shorter. `maplist/2,3...` are very powerful predicates, they subsume map, zip, zipWith in functional languages.

Comment: Just one more question please. I have never used the operator 'when' and I searched it on Google but I didn't found anything. What's the differences between when and doing an 'if'

Comment: A goal `when(Cond, Goal)` means `Goal`, but it will wait to execute `Goal` until `Cond` is satisfied. I am not sure which if you are referring to, there is `(;)/2` if-then-else, `(->)/2` and `if/3` or `(*->)/2`. In any case, all these do not delay execution as when/2 does it.

Comment: Because of `maplist(\_^_^true, Xs, Ys)`, [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org) raises `procedure \`(A,B,C)' does not exist` for the query `time(list_sorted2([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],Xs)).`. Even when adding `use_module(library(lambda)).` or `use_module(library(apply)).` at the beginning of the program.

Comment: @Maggyero: Seems to be broken.

Comment: What does `\_^_^true` mean?

Answer (score 4):

As an encore I have run a [sorting network generator](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html) for the length `10` and ported the code (that was generated with option "best") to Prolog/clpfd.

Here comes `list_sorted__SN10/2` (`SN10` stands for "sorting network size 10"):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_sorted__SN10(Xs,Zs) :-
    Xs = [A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9],
    Zs = [E0,G1,H2,I3,J4,J5,I6,H7,G8,E9],
    B4 #= min(A4,A9),  B9 #= max(A4,A9),
    B3 #= min(A3,A8),  B8 #= max(A3,A8),
    B2 #= min(A2,A7),  B7 #= max(A2,A7),
    B1 #= min(A1,A6),  B6 #= max(A1,A6),
    B0 #= min(A0,A5),  B5 #= max(A0,A5),
    C1 #= min(B1,B4),  C4 #= max(B1,B4),
    C6 #= min(B6,B9),  C9 #= max(B6,B9),
    C0 #= min(B0,B3),  C3 #= max(B0,B3),
    C5 #= min(B5,B8),  C8 #= max(B5,B8),
    D0 #= min(C0,B2),  D2 #= max(C0,B2),
    D3 #= min(C3,C6),  D6 #= max(C3,C6),
    D7 #= min(B7,C9),  D9 #= max(B7,C9),
    E0 #= min(D0,C1),  E1 #= max(D0,C1),
    E2 #= min(D2,C4),  E4 #= max(D2,C4),
    E5 #= min(C5,D7),  E7 #= max(C5,D7),
    E8 #= min(C8,D9),  E9 #= max(C8,D9),
    F1 #= min(E1,E2),  F2 #= max(E1,E2),
    F4 #= min(E4,D6),  F6 #= max(E4,D6),
    F7 #= min(E7,E8),  F8 #= max(E7,E8),
    F3 #= min(D3,E5),  F5 #= max(D3,E5),
    G2 #= min(F2,F5),  G5 #= max(F2,F5),
    G6 #= min(F6,F8),  G8 #= max(F6,F8),
    G1 #= min(F1,F3),  G3 #= max(F1,F3),
    G4 #= min(F4,F7),  G7 #= max(F4,F7),
    H2 #= min(G2,G3),  H3 #= max(G2,G3),
    H6 #= min(G6,G7),  H7 #= max(G6,G7),
    I3 #= min(H3,G4),  I4 #= max(H3,G4),
    I5 #= min(G5,H6),  I6 #= max(G5,H6),
    J4 #= min(I4,I5),  J5 #= max(I4,I5).
```

Let's see if it works:

```
?- numlist(1,10,Xs),permutation(Xs,Ys),\+ list_sorted__SN10(Ys,Xs).
false.              % all permutations are sorted correctly
```

What about going in the other direction?

```
?- list_sorted__SN10(Xs,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),
   labeling([],Xs),
   write('Xs'=Xs),nl,
   false.
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8,10]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,8]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,8,9]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,9,8]
Xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,10]
...
```

Got speed?

```
?- time(list_sorted__SN10([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],Xs)).
% 198 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 4841431 Lips)
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

*Got speed!*

---

## Handling the general case

Sorting lists `Xs` with `length(Xs,10)` is nice, but what if I have longer or shorter ones?

Once again, [sorting networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) to the rescue!

Here's a Prolog/clpfd port of the code shown in [Bitonic sorting network for n not a power of 2](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/bitonic/oddn.htm); the Prolog code uses attributed variables for random read/write access of the items to be sorted. We use an attribute `value` which stores the item at that particular position at that time.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

init_att_var(X,Z) :-
    put_attr(Z,value,X).

get_att_value(Var,Value) :-
    get_attr(Var,value,Value).

direction_flipped(ascending,descending).
direction_flipped(descending,ascending).

fdBitonicSort(Xs0,Zs) :-
    same_length(Xs0,Zs),
    maplist(init_att_var,Xs0,Xs1),
    Xs2 =.. [data|Xs1],
    functor(Xs2,_,N),    
    fdBitonicSort_(Xs2,0,N,ascending),
    maplist(get_att_value,Xs1,Zs).
```

The recursive breakdown required for bitonic sorting is accomplished by the following code:

```
fdBitonicSort_(Data,Lo,N,Dir) :-
    (  N > 1
    -> M is N // 2,
       direction_flipped(Dir,Dir1),
       fdBitonicSort_(Data,Lo,M,Dir1),
       Lo1 is Lo + M,
       N1  is N  - M,
       fdBitonicSort_(Data,Lo1,N1,Dir),
       fdBitonicMerge_(Data,Lo,N,Dir)
    ;  true
    ).

greatestPowerOfTwoLessThan(N,K) :- 
    T is 1 << msb(N),
    (  N /\ (N-1) =:= 0 
    -> K is T >> 1
    ;  K = T
    ).

fdBitonicMerge_(Data,Lo,N,Dir) :-
    (  N > 1
    -> greatestPowerOfTwoLessThan(N,M),
       Ub is Lo + N - M,
       fdBitonicCompareMany_(Data,Lo,Ub,M,Dir),
       fdBitonicMerge_(Data,Lo,M,Dir),
       Lo1 is Lo + M,
       N1  is N  - M,
       fdBitonicMerge_(Data,Lo1,N1,Dir)
    ;  true
    ).
```

The inner loop of comparisons looks like this:

```
fdBitonicCompareMany_(Data,I,Ub,M,Dir) :-
    (  I < Ub
    -> I_plus_M is I+M,
       fdBitonicCompareTwo_(Data,I,I_plus_M,Dir),
       I1 is I + 1,
       fdBitonicCompareMany_(Data,I1,Ub,M,Dir)
    ;  true
    ).
```

*Almost done!* One thing's missing... `fdBitonicCompareTwo_/4` reads the i-th and the j-th item and puts the minimum and maximum in the i-th and j-th place if the direction is `ascending`. If the direction is `descending` the minimum and maximum are put in the j-th and i-th place:

```
fdBitonicCompareTwo_(Data,I,J,Dir) :-
    I1 is I+1,
    J1 is J+1,
    arg(I1,Data,V1),
    arg(J1,Data,V2),
    get_attr(V1,value,W1),
    get_attr(V2,value,W2),
    Z1 #= min(W1,W2),
    Z2 #= max(W1,W2),
    (  Dir == ascending
    -> E1 = Z1, E2 = Z2
    ;  E1 = Z2, E2 = Z1
    ),
    put_attr(V1,value,E1),
    put_attr(V2,value,E2).
```

#### Testing

First, 10 times for every list length between `1` and `200` take random numbers between `1` and `10000` and sort them. Scream out loud if the result differs from what `msort/2` delivers.

```
?- (  setrand(rand(29989,9973,997)),
      between(1,200,N),
      length(Xs,N), 
      format('(~d)',[N]),
      ( N mod 10 =:= 0 -> nl ; true ),
      between(1,10,_),
      maplist(random_between(1,10000),Xs),
      (  fdBitonicSort(Xs,Zs), \+ msort(Xs,Zs) 
      -> write(error(Xs,Zs)), nl
      ;  true
      ),
      false
   ;  true
   ).
(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)
(11)(12)(13)(14)(15)(16)(17)(18)(19)(20)
(21)(22)(23)(24)(25)(26)(27)(28)(29)(30)
(31)(32)(33)(34)(35)(36)(37)(38)(39)(40)
(41)(42)(43)(44)(45)(46)(47)(48)(49)(50)
(51)(52)(53)(54)(55)(56)(57)(58)(59)(60)
(61)(62)(63)(64)(65)(66)(67)(68)(69)(70)
(71)(72)(73)(74)(75)(76)(77)(78)(79)(80)
(81)(82)(83)(84)(85)(86)(87)(88)(89)(90)
(91)(92)(93)(94)(95)(96)(97)(98)(99)(100)
(101)(102)(103)(104)(105)(106)(107)(108)(109)(110)
(111)(112)(113)(114)(115)(116)(117)(118)(119)(120)
(121)(122)(123)(124)(125)(126)(127)(128)(129)(130)
(131)(132)(133)(134)(135)(136)(137)(138)(139)(140)
(141)(142)(143)(144)(145)(146)(147)(148)(149)(150)
(151)(152)(153)(154)(155)(156)(157)(158)(159)(160)
(161)(162)(163)(164)(165)(166)(167)(168)(169)(170)
(171)(172)(173)(174)(175)(176)(177)(178)(179)(180)
(181)(182)(183)(184)(185)(186)(187)(188)(189)(190)
(191)(192)(193)(194)(195)(196)(197)(198)(199)(200)
true.
```

Next, take lists from `1` to `N` (with `N =< Ub`), consider all permutations and see it any one of them shows a bug in bitonic sorting (a result that differs from what `msort/2` gives us).

The test is done in two different ways: `after` and `before`. `after` builds up the constraint network and *then* binds the FD variables to concrete values.
`before` does it the other way round, effectively using clpfd as integer arithmetic---all constraints are immediately resolved.

```
test_fdBitonicSort(Method,Ub) :-
    length(RefList,Ub),
    append(Xs,_,RefList),
    length(Xs,N),
    numlist(1,N,Xs),
    same_length(Xs,Ys),
    same_length(Xs,Zs),
    time((format('[~q] testing length ~d (all permutations of ~q) ... ',
                 [Method,N,Xs]),
          (  Method == before
          -> (  permutation(Xs,Ys),
                \+ fdBitonicSort(Ys,Xs)
             -> write(errorB(Ys))
             ;  true 
             )
          ;  permutation(Xs,Ys),
             \+ (fdBitonicSort(Zs,Xs), Zs = Ys)
          -> write(errorA(Ys))
          ;  true
          ),
          write('DONE\n'))),
    false.
test_fdBitonicSort(_,_).
```

Let's run `test_fdBitonicSort/2`:

```
?- test_fdBitonicSort(after,7).
[after] testing length 1 (all permutations of [1]) ... DONE
% 93 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (89% CPU, 1620943 Lips)
[after] testing length 2 (all permutations of [1,2]) ... DONE
% 4,775 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 9136675 Lips)
[after] testing length 3 (all permutations of [1,2,3]) ... DONE
% 53,739 inferences, 0.006 CPU in 0.006 seconds (100% CPU, 9514148 Lips)
[after] testing length 4 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4]) ... DONE
% 462,798 inferences, 0.048 CPU in 0.048 seconds (100% CPU, 9652164 Lips)
[after] testing length 5 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5]) ... DONE
% 3,618,226 inferences, 0.374 CPU in 0.374 seconds (100% CPU, 9666074 Lips)
[after] testing length 6 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6]) ... DONE
% 32,890,387 inferences, 3.212 CPU in 3.211 seconds (100% CPU, 10241324 Lips)
[after] testing length 7 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) ... DONE
% 330,442,005 inferences, 32.499 CPU in 32.493 seconds (100% CPU, 10167747 Lips)
true.
```

Let's use the predicate again, this time with ground input:

```
?- test_fdBitonicSort(before,9).
[before] testing length 1 (all permutations of [1]) ... DONE
% 27 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 334208 Lips)
[before] testing length 2 (all permutations of [1,2]) ... DONE
% 151 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 1824884 Lips)
[before] testing length 3 (all permutations of [1,2,3]) ... DONE
% 930 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 4308089 Lips)
[before] testing length 4 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4]) ... DONE
% 6,033 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 5124516 Lips)
[before] testing length 5 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5]) ... DONE
% 43,584 inferences, 0.006 CPU in 0.006 seconds (100% CPU, 7722860 Lips)
[before] testing length 6 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6]) ... DONE
% 353,637 inferences, 0.033 CPU in 0.033 seconds (100% CPU, 10753040 Lips)
[before] testing length 7 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) ... DONE
% 3,201,186 inferences, 0.249 CPU in 0.249 seconds (100% CPU, 12844003 Lips)
[before] testing length 8 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) ... DONE
% 32,060,649 inferences, 2.595 CPU in 2.594 seconds (100% CPU, 12355290 Lips)
[before] testing length 9 (all permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) ... DONE
% 340,437,636 inferences, 27.549 CPU in 27.541 seconds (100% CPU, 12357591 Lips)
true.
```

It works! Is there more to do? *Yes*, **definitely**!

First, specialized code like `list_sorted__SN10/2` should be generated for other small sizes. Second, one might evaluate different equivalent network sorting methods.

Comment: A seed is needed for reproducible results.

Comment: @mat. By coincidence I was looking into the code of http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sicstus%3Aget_mutable/2 ... I had forgotten that API even existed (I surely had used before, in SICStus3 days)! So I was "forced" to ask the bigger question...

Answer (score 3):

Here are *two* implementations using clpfd. Both are similar to the "permutation sort" variants presented in earlier answers. However, both express "permutation" not by using `permutation/2`, but by a combination of [`element/3`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Extensional-Constraints.html) and [`all_distinct/1`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints.html).

`element/3` states that the elements of the sorted list are all members of the original list. `all_distinct/1` ensures that the element indices are all different from each other.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

elements_index_item(Vs,N,V) :-
    element(N,Vs,V).

list_sortedA(Xs,Zs) :-
    same_length(Xs,Zs),
    chain(Zs,#=<),
    maplist(elements_index_item(Xs),Ns,Zs),
    all_distinct(Ns),
    labeling([],Ns).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_sorted1([9,7,8,5,6,3,4,1,2],Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] ;
false.
```

What if the *second* argument is known and the first is unknown?

```
?- list_sorted1(Xs,[1,2,3]).
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 3, 2] ;
Xs = [2, 1, 3] ;
Xs = [3, 1, 2] ;
Xs = [2, 3, 1] ;
Xs = [3, 2, 1].
```

So far, so good. What if the list to be sorted contains *duplicates*?

```
?- list_sorted1([5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5].
```

Now that's a lot of redundant answers! Can we do better?

---

### Eliminating redundant answers

Yes! The redundant answers in the above query can be eliminated by adding a constraint relating neighboring items in the sorted list and their respective positions in the original list.

The constraint `Z1 #= Z2 #==> N1 #< N2` states: "If two neighboring items in the sorted list are equal then their positions in the original list must be ordered."

```
originalPosition_sorted([],[]).
originalPosition_sorted([_],[_]).
originalPosition_sorted([N1,N2|Ns],[Z1,Z2|Zs]) :-
    Z1 #= Z2 #==> N1 #< N2,
    originalPosition_sorted([N2|Ns],[Z2|Zs]).

list_sorted2(Xs,Zs) :-
    same_length(Xs,Zs),
    chain(Zs,#=<),
    maplist(elements_index_item(Xs),Ns,Zs),
    originalPosition_sorted(Ns,Zs),
    all_distinct(Ns),
    labeling([],Ns).
```

But... does it work?

```
?- list_sorted2([5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] ;
false.
```