# Prolog: How can I implement the sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three?

Tags: prolog, sicp, logic-programming

Exercise 1.3 of the book [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) asks the following:

> Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

I'm learning Prolog. Here's the function I tried to implement:

```
square(X, Y) :- Y is X * X.
squareTwoLargest(X, Y, Z, R) :- 
    R is square(L1) + square(L2), L1 = max(X, Y), L2 = max(min(X, Y), Z).
```

However, when I run it, it gives the following error: `ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. I think I'm not only not getting Prolog's syntax, but I'm also not getting the logic programming paradigm yet. So, how could I implement this function in good logic programming style?

Comment: Put the `=` goals in front of `is`

Comment: The `is/2` operator requires that the second argument be fully instantiated. Also, Prolog has *predicates*, not *functions*. A *predicate* succeeds or fails (or fails to terminate :)) and does not "return" a value. It can, however instantiate arguments. So your use of `square` won't work. Your use of `min(X, Y)` will also be problematic.

Comment: @lurker So, I would have to actually write `R is L1 * L1 + L2 * L2`?

Comment: @false Why does it work with the `=`in front of `is` (provided I also wrote `R is L1 * L1 + L2 * L2`instead of using `square`?

Comment: Yes, or do `square(L1, S1), square(L2, S2), R is S1 + S2`

Comment: You can write `L1^2` in place of `square(L1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `max` function you are using, is built-in arithmetic function and does not behave as a predicate, this may trick you into thinking that you will write your predicates in the same way.

In Prolog, what you will be writing is predicates. Predicate does not return any value, it just holds or does not hold (you can think of it as if it returned `true` or `false`). Your predicate `square` is a good example, what it `square(X,Y)` really means is 'Y is square of X'. If you ask Prolog console `square(4, 16).`, it will tell you `true`. If you ask `square(4, 44)`, it will tell you `false`. So how do you find out square root of some number? You ask Prolog a question with free (unknown) variable `square(4,R).`, then Prolog will tell you that `R=16`. That is the important part of logical programming, you do not explain Prolog, how to calculate square, you only tell Prolog what square is in terms of logic and then you ask Prolog question and it will find answer by itself.

Soo what if you try instead of

```
R is square(L1) + square(L2)
```

something like

```
square(L2, L2SQUARED), square(L1, L1SQUARED), ...
```

which will give you square of L1 in L1SQUARED

However, L1 must not be free variable, Prolog must be able to deduce some value for it based on some other predicates (...), so that it can answer to `square(L1, L1SQUARED)`. Imagine question `square(SOMETHING1, SOMETHING2)`, where both arguments are unknown, what will the answer be? There is infinite number of correct answers, for example [2, 4] or [3, 9] etc.

Note: yes, it can be onliner with arithmetics, but if you want to learn logical programming, try more 'logical programming' like approach. In some flavours of Prolog, you do not get arithmetics and they are still useful...

Comment: How would a more logical programming approach look like? That's the main reason why I want to learn Prolog.

Comment: A logic programming approach would be to use *constraints* instead of lower-level arithmetic. Constraints work in all directions, also if parts of expressions are not yet known. Check your implementation for CLP(Q), CLP(FD) and CLP(R) features.

Answer (score 2):

To get the two largest numbers out of three (`V1`, `V2`, and `V3`) you can proceed as follows: Sort the list `[V1,V2,V3]` and take the last two list items `[_,X,Y]`, square and sum them.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

squareTwoLargest(V1,V2,V3, R) :- 
    Zs = [_,X,Y],
    chain(Zs, #=<),
    permutation([V1,V2,V3],Zs),
    R #= X*X + Y*Y.
```

Sample query:

```
?- squareTwoLargest(20,30,10, R).
R = 1300
```

---

#### Better implementation

Above code is based on "permutation sort", which makes it inefficient in more than one way.

The goal `squareTwoLargest(X,Y,Z, R)` succeeds multiple times and gives redundant answers, if two or more of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are equal. This is shown by the following two queries:

```
?- squareTwoLargest(0,10,10, R).
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
false.

?- squareTwoLargest(10,10,10, R).
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
R = 200 ;
false.
```

We can eliminate the redundant answers by using a sorting network of size 3. For details, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214266/ordering-lists-with-constraint-logic-programming/29657722#29657722) to the question 
[ordering lists with constraint logic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214266/ordering-lists-with-constraint-logic-programming).

```
list_sorted__SN3([A0,A1,A2], [D0,D1,C2]) :-
    B1 #= min(A1,A2),   B2 #= max(A1,A2),
    C0 #= min(A0,B2),   C2 #= max(A0,B2),
    D0 #= min(C0,B1),   D1 #= max(C0,B1).

squareTwoLargest__SN(V1,V2,V3, R) :-
    list_sorted__SN3([V1,V2,V3],[_,X,Y]),
    R #= X*X + Y*Y.
```

Consider the following queries:

```
?- squareTwoLargest__SN(20,30,10, R).
R = 1300.                              % works like it did before

?- squareTwoLargest__SN(20,20,10, R).
R = 800.                               % succeeds deterministically

?- squareTwoLargest__SN(20,20,20, R).
R = 800.                               % succeeds deterministically
```

Note that all redundant answers of the corner cases shown above have been eliminated.

Comment: Great solution, +1! Please see also the discussion on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/86805/27679).

Answer (score 1):

my bet, using the 'if-then-else' construct.

```
squareTwoLargest(X, Y, Z, R) :- 
    ( X > Y -> A = X, B = Y ; A = Y, B = X ),
    R is A + max(B, Z).
```

Two temp variables are needed.

Comment: Your original function "returned" the sum of the two largest, not the sum of the square of the two largest (writing `R is A * A + max(B, Z) * max(B, Z)` did the trick). I wrote "returned" because I'm starting to think that "returned" is a wrong word to use in Prolog.

Comment: oops, I focused on the tricky part (selecting 2 greatest values...) so I misunderstood the question.