# Making "deterministic success" of Prolog goals explicit

Tags: prolog

The matter of deterministic success of some Prolog goal has turned up time and again in—at least—the following questions:

- [Reification of term equality/inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality)
- [Intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists)
- [Remove duplicates in list (Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260792/remove-duplicates-in-list-prolog)
- [Prolog: How can I implement the sum of squares of two largest numbers out of three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613789/prolog-how-can-i-implement-the-sum-of-squares-of-two-largest-numbers-out-of-thr)
- [Ordering lists with constraint logic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214266/ordering-lists-with-constraint-logic-programming))

Different methods were used (e.g., provoking certain resource errors, or looking closely at the exact answers given by the Prolog toplevel), but they all appear somewhat ad-hack to me.

I'm looking for a generic, portable, and ISO-conformant way to find out if the execution of some Prolog goal (which succeeded) left some choice-point(s) behind. Some meta predicate, maybe?

Could you please hint me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's *ad hack**em***

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good news everyone: `setup_call_cleanup/3` (currently a [draft proposal](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/cleanup) for ISO) lets you do that in a quite portable and beautiful way.

See the [example](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3):

`setup_call_cleanup(true, (X=1;X=2), Det=yes)`

succeeds with `Det == yes` when there are no more choice points left.

---

**EDIT**: Let me illustrate the awesomeness of this construct, or rather of the very closely related predicate `call_cleanup/2`, with a simple example:

In the excellent [CLP(B) documentation of SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/CLPB-Interface.html#CLPB-Interface), we find in the description of `labeling/1` a very strong guarantee:

> Enumerates all solutions by backtracking, but **creates choicepoints only if necessary**.

This is really a strong guarantee, and at first it may be hard to believe that it always holds. Luckily for us, it is extremely easy to formulate and generate systematic test cases in Prolog to verify such properties, in essence using the Prolog system to test itself.

We start with systematically describing what a Boolean *expression* looks like in CLP(B):

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

sat(_) --> [].
sat(a) --> [].
sat(~_) --> [].
sat(X+Y) --> [_], sat(X), sat(Y).
sat(X#Y) --> [_], sat(X), sat(Y).
```

There are in fact many more cases, but let us restrict ourselves to the above subset of CLP(B) expressions for now.

Why am I using a DCG for this? Because it lets me conveniently describe (a subset of) all Boolean expressions *of specific depth*, and thus fairly enumerate them all. For example:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(sat(Sat), Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [],
Sat = a ;
Ls = [],
Sat = ~_G475 ;
Ls = [_G475],
Sat = _G478+_G479 .
```

Thus, I am using the DCG only to denote how many available "tokens" have already been consumed when generating expressions, limiting the total depth of the resulting expressions.

Next, we need a small auxiliary predicate `labeling_nondet/1`, which acts exactly as `labeling/1`, but is only true if a choice-point *still remains*. This is where `call_cleanup/2` comes in:

```
labeling_nondet(Vs) :-
        dif(Det, true),
        call_cleanup(labeling(Vs), Det=true).
```

Our **test case** (and by this, we actually mean an infinite sequence of small test cases, which we can very conveniently describe with Prolog) now aims to verify the above property, i.e.:

> If there is a choice-point, then there is a further solution.

In other words:

> The set of solutions of `labeling_nondet/1` is a proper subset of that of `labeling/1`.

Let us thus describe what a **counterexample** of the above property looks like:

```
counterexample(Sat) :-
        length(Ls, _),
        phrase(sat(Sat), Ls),
        term_variables(Sat, Vs),
        sat(Sat),
        setof(Vs, labeling_nondet(Vs), Sols),
        setof(Vs, labeling(Vs), Sols).
```

And now we use this executable specification in order to find such a counterexample. If the solver works as documented, then we will never find a counterexample. But in this case, we immediately get:

```
| ?- counterexample(Sat).
Sat = a+ ~_A,
sat(_A=:=_B*a) ? ;
```

So in fact the property does *not* hold. Broken down to the essence, although no more solutions remain in the following query, `Det` is not unified with `true`:

```
| ?- sat(a + ~X), call_cleanup(labeling([X]), Det=true).
X = 0 ? ;
no
```

In SWI-Prolog, the superfluous choice-point is obvious:

```
?- sat(a + ~X), labeling([X]).
X = 0 ;
false.
```

I am *not* giving this example to criticize the behaviour of either SICStus Prolog or SWI: Nobody really cares whether or not a superfluous choice-point is left in `labeling/1`, least of all in an artificial example that involves universally quantified variables (which is atypical for tasks in which one uses `labeling/1`).

I *am* giving this example to show how nicely and conveniently guarantees that are documented and intended can be tested with such powerful inspection predicates...

... assuming that implementors are interested to standardize their efforts, so that these predicates actually work the same way across different implementations! The attentive reader will have noticed that the search for counterexamples produces quite different results when used in SWI-Prolog.

In an unexpected turn of events, the above test case has found a discrepancy in the `call_cleanup/2` implementations of SWI-Prolog and SICStus. In SWI-Prolog (7.3.11):

```
?- dif(Det, true), call_cleanup(true, Det=true).
dif(Det, true).

?- call_cleanup(true, Det=true), dif(Det, true).
false.
```

whereas both queries *fail* in SICStus Prolog (4.3.2).

This is the quite typical case: Once you are interested in testing a specific property, you find many obstacles that are in the way of testing the actual property.

In the ISO [draft proposal](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/cleanup), we see:

> Failure of [the cleanup goal] is **ignored**.

In the SICStus documentation of [call_cleanup/2](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dcall_005fcleanup.html#mpg_002dref_002dcall_005fcleanup), we see:

> Cleanup succeeds determinately after performing some side-effect; otherwise, **unexpected behavior** may result.

And in the [SWI variant](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3), we see:

> Success or failure of Cleanup is **ignored**

Thus, for portability, we should actually write `labeling_nondet/1` as:

```
labeling_nondet(Vs) :-
        call_cleanup(labeling(Vs), Det=true),
        dif(Det, true).
```

Comment: We all love a good hack. But, as with Duff's Device, this highlights a problem with the language construct: A built-in purporting to serve the purpose of cleanup leaks implementation-level information.

Comment: I find it awesome that this predicate is so versatile that, while on the surface concerned with cleanups, it is expressive enough that the determinism information, which I think is valuable in several situations and should therefore be accessible, can easily be extracted with it.

Comment: Sure, it's "awesome". What I'm saying is that it's bad design ;)

Comment: Once the existence of the problem is accepted, alternative solutions are not hard to find and can be evaluated, preferably outside a social website's comment section.

Comment: @jschimpf: Do you have in the meantime a proposal that is not (as you said) "bad design"?

Comment: @mat: w.r.t. your recent changes: There is still a lot to do to improve the current document [post-N215](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/cleanup). Any contributions welcome! For your example, one would need that also `dif/2` is codified, which it is currently not...

Comment: I downvoted because setup_call_cleanup/3 is not meant to be such awesome as you believe. The determinism detection is only an optional feature, why do you think this is ISO draft proposal?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee in setup_call_cleanup/3 that it detects determinism, i.e. missing choice points in the success of a goal. The 7.8.11.1 Description [draft proposal](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/N215) only says:

> c) The cleanup handler is called exactly once; no later than
>   upon failure of G. Earlier moments are:
>   If G is true or false, C is called at an **implementation**
>   dependent moment after the last solution and after the last
>   observable effect of G.

So there is currently no requirement that:

```
setup_call_cleanup(true, true, Det=true)
```

Returns Det=true in the first place. This is also reflected in the test cases 7.8.11.4 Examples that the [draf proposal](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/N215) gives, we find one test case which says:

```
setup_call_cleanup(true, true, X = 2).
Either: Succeeds, unifying X = 2.
Or: Succeeds.
```

So its both a valid implementation, to detect determinism and not to detect determinism.

Comment: As an implementor, you are always well advised to go above and beyond what the standard prescribes. You must read the standard as ensuring the *absolute minimum* requirements, and as you already see in all actual implementations of `setup_call_cleanup/3`, the available systems go well beyond this minimum in actually calling the cleanup as soon as possible!

Comment: That's OK, though still no reason to downvote an answer that shows how to use this predicate in systems that go beyond what the standard prescribes, and even include such an example in their documentation.

Comment: I explicitly say that it is **quite** portable. Please actually read the posts you are voting on.

Comment: The good thing is that most of the ISO documents, draft or standard, currently maintained by Ulrich Neumerkel, are very carful in their specifications. Many many features are implementation dependent, and thus not necessarely required by all Prolog system implementations.

Comment: Maybe the misbelive comes from a wrong claim here: "setup_call_cleanup/3 can also be used to test determinism of a goal, providing a portable alternative to deterministic/1", http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3