# Permutations of power set in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am supposed to write a program in Prolog which when given a list,returns the permutation of its powerset.
**one thing I forgot to mention: I already have a predicate that reverses a list: deep_reverse(List,RevList).**
for example: `?-sublist_perm([a,b,c],X).`
will return:(duplicates are allowed)

```
 X = [] ;
 X = [c] ;
 X = [b] ;
 X = [b, c] ;
 X = [c, b] ;
 X = [a] ;
 X = [a, c] ;
 X = [c, a] ;
 X = [a, b] ;
 X = [b, a] ;
 X = [a, b, c] ;
 X = [b, a, c] ;
 X = [b, c, a] ;
 X = [a, c, b] ;
 X = [c, a, b] ;
 X = [c, b, a]
```

Comment: Show us the "bunch of different stuff" you did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gnu Prolog powerset modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146117/gnu-prolog-powerset-modification)

Comment: I looked at it, its not the same.

Comment: I had one try that was extremely close but it was an ugly code and I deleted all of them trying every time to start over fresh

Comment: The third result of a search for permutation finds [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196570/prolog-how-to-write-and-use-a-function-that-lists-all-list-permutations) with code. The question I linked to above has code for generating a powerset. Spend 30 seconds with both and you can solve the problem yourself. And next time bring your ugly but close code so we don't feel like we're being asked to do your homework for you.

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll check it out, and yeah next time I promise to bring my code, just don't kill me

Answer (score 4):

You ask two things in one question: How to get all sublists and how to permutate a list:

```
sublist_perm(In, Out) :-
    sublist(In, Temp),
    permutation(Temp, Out).

sublist([], []).
sublist([_|XS], YS) :-
    sublist(XS, YS).
sublist([X|XS], [X|YS]) :-
    sublist(XS, YS).
```

See also: [man page for permutation/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation%2F2).

```
findall(X, sublist_perm([a,b,c], X), XS),
XS = [[],[c],[b],[b,c],[c,b],[a],[a,c],[c,a],[a,b],[b,a],
      [a,b,c],[b,a,c],[b,c,a],[a,c,b],[c,a,b],[c,b,a]].
```